# Post Complex Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Diving in ASP.NET WebAPI, I'm sending HTTP Post/Put to the server, but no values are returned, Looks like WebApi doesn't recognize the values provided.

Why I can't get the values returned? I'm missing something?

I Have this "complex" class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using CoreAPI.DB.Tables;

namespace CoreAPI.Controllers.RequestObjects
{
    public class CompanyBuildingObject
    {
        public int Id;
        public int Company_Id;
        public int Building_Id;
        public int[] BuildingUnit_Id;

        public CompanyBuildingObject()
        {
        }
     }
}
```

This is the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using CoreAPI.DB.Tables;
using CoreAPI.Controllers.RequestObjects;

namespace CoreAPI.Controllers
{
    public class CompanyBuildingsController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDatabase db = new ApplicationDatabase();
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("api/CompanyBuildings/PutSyncCompanyBuildingUnits/{id}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(CompanyBuildingObject))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutSynCompanyBuildingUnits(int id, CompanyBuildingObject companyBuildingObject)
    {
        return Ok(companyBuildingObject);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/CompanyBuildings/PostSyncCompanyBuildingUnits/{id}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(CompanyBuildingObject))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostSynCompanyBuildingUnits(int id, CompanyBuildingObject companyBuildingObject)
    {
        return Ok(companyBuildingObject);
    }
}
```

[image: This is the fields that are posted from browser using $.ajax]

This is the postman test

[image]

Comment: Try `(int id, [FromBody] CompanyBuildingObject companyBuildingObject)`

Comment: Thanks @SlavaUtesinov but It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your sending Posting VIA Json. Your format should look like this.

```
{
    "id": 3634,
    "CompanyBuildingObject":{
        "Id":1,
        "Company_Id":2,
         "Building_Id":2,
         "BuildingUnit_Id":[1,2,3,4]
    }
}
```

Try a [POST Man](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) or any client to post data to your API.

Instead of form-urlencoded try "RAW" with `json` format

Comment: Thanks for your support, But the core class that send request is not using json raw parameters, I've tested with PostMan previously and works great. I found another way that works, Checkout the answer below. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the implementation of Properties that access for read/write the private fields. Now is working and this is the class currently.

```
public class CompanyBuildingObject
{
    private int _CompanyId = 0;
    private int _BuildingId = 0;
    private int _BuildingUnitId = 0;

    public int Company_Id
    {
        get { return _CompanyId; }
        set { _CompanyId = value; }
    }

    public int Building_Id
    {
        get { return _BuildingId; }
        set { _BuildingId = value; }
    }

    public int BuildingUnit_Id
    {
        get { return _BuildingUnitId; }
        set { _BuildingUnitId = value; }
    }

    public CompanyBuildingObject()
    {
        Company_Id = 0;
        Building_Id = 0;
        BuildingUnit_Id = 0;
    }
}


    [HttpPut]
    [ResponseType(typeof(CompanyBuildingUnit))]
    [Route("api/CompanyBuildingUnits/PutCompanyBuildingUnit/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult PutCompanyBuildingUnit(int id, CompanyBuildingObject cbo)
    {
        return Ok(SyncCompanyBuildingUnits(id, cbo));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(CompanyBuildingUnit))]
    [Route("api/CompanyBuildingUnits/PostCompanyBuildingUnit/")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostCompanyBuildingUnit(CompanyBuildingObject cbo)
    {
        return Ok(SyncCompanyBuildingUnits(0, cbo));
    }
```